# android - how to use recycleview's OnScrollListener in scrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

I need to use recycleview inside scrollview . I use this but I've a problem , I need to use OnScrollListener  with my recycleview for getting new data when user reaches the end of recyleview , this problem is ,it not being called when I use recyleview inside scrollview .

this is my code :

```
<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager.AutoScrollViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/pager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

I've a frameLayout that returns my fragment and the fragment contains a recycleview .

this is my java code but it's just called once and not calling again when I scroll recyeleview :

```
ads.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            Log.v("this","Scroll");
            visibleItemCount = ads.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loadmore) {
                if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                    previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                }
            }
            if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                    <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                if (taskrunning != null && taskrunning == false && loadmore) {
                    loadmore = false;
                    page = page + 1;
                    new AsyncHttpTask(1).execute(url);
                }

            }
        }

    });
```

how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: why would you use scrollView? RecyclerView already manages scrolling by itself.